# (NOT) NULL for NVARCHAR columns

Tags: sql

Allowing `NULL` values on a column is normally done to allow the absense of a value to be represented. When using `NVARCHAR` there is aldready a possibility to have an empty string, without setting the column to `NULL`. In most cases I cannot see a semantical difference between an `NVARCHAR` with an empty string and a `NULL` value for such a column.

Setting the column as `NOT NULL` saves me from having to deal with the possibility of `NULL` values in the code and it feels better to not have to different representations of "no value" (`NULL` or an empty string).

Will I run into any other problems by setting my `NVARCHAR` columns to `NOT NULL`. Performance? Storage size? Anything I've overlooked on the usage of the values in the client code?

Comment: Well, Oracle agrees with you and treats empty strings as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NULL` indicates that the value in the column is missing/inapplicable.  A blank string is different because that is an actual value.  A `NULL` technically has no data type where as a blank string, in this case, is nvarchar.

I cant see any issues with having default values rather than `NULL` values.

In fact, it would probably be beneficial as you wouldn't have to worry about catering for `NULL` values in any of your queries

e.g

```
Select Sum(TotalPrice) as 'TotalPrice' From myTable Where CountOfItems > 10
```

much easier than

```
Select Sum(IsNull(TotalPrice,0)) as 'TotalPrice' From myTable Where IsNull(CountOfItems,0) > 10
```

You should use default constraints in your DDL to ensure that no rogue `NULL`'s appear in your data.

Comment: -1 If `TotalPrice` is `NULL` then it won't be included in the aggregate anyway. If `CountOfItems` is `NULL` then it won't match the predicate `>10` anyway so both these are redundant and the second one just makes the expression unsargable. Also what if you use `AVG` rather than `SUM`? Now your dummy values will make the result incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of the NULL value is a common source of confusion. NULL is *not* the same as an empty string, or a value of zero.

Conceptually, NULL means "a missing unknown value" and it is treated somewhat differently from other values. For example, to test for NULL, you cannot use the arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <>.

If you have columns that may contain "a missing unknown value", you have to set them to accept NULLs. On the other hand, an empty string simply means that the value *is known*, but is empty.

For example: If a "Middle Name" field in a "Users" table is set to NULL, it should mean that the middle name of that user is not known. The user might or might not have a middle name. However, if the "Middle Name" field is set to an empty string, this should mean that the user is known to have no middle name.

Comment: Yes and no, it depends on the application.  There are plenty of use cases where you'll find certain fields for which empty string and null string do not have/need separate meanings.

Answer (score 0):

If anything I'd say that it'll be easier to use the table if you don't allow NULLs, since you won't have to check for NULLs everywhere in code, so I'd only set a column to allow NULLs if I need to handle unknown rather than empty values.

Answer (score 0):

What ho1 said. But you'd be ill-advised to define a column NOT NULL and then have a special value for 'Unknown'.